# Use Spline interpolation in WebGL

Tags: javascript, html, webgl

How can I use spline interpolation in 3D with WebGL?. This is for molecule modeling, specifically Trace representation. I have been searching information about it, but i hven't found how to use it in WebGL. Will  i need create the algorithm?

Comment: What values do you need to interpolate? Are they texture samples?

Comment: The values are given by a PDB file(http://www.rcsb.org/pdb/home/home.do), i have this https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3_ICNPXK86mR2lBQVluR3ZhSGc but i need a spline like this http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/560163/testSpline.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use it, but there're no ready-to-use facilities in WebGL. What you need to do is instead of generating geometry for strait lines between atoms (?) generate appropriately segmented splines. Also, WebGL 2 geometry shaders may come in handy to generate such splines in a performant manner.

However, if you're implementing a molecular viewer or editor and need to display alpha helices, beta sheets and such for a protein, maybe the best way would be to render them as pre-made primitives (e.g., modeled in a 3d software, exported and used as a ready geometry).